# Що означає слово "фана"?

Tags: значення-слів

Читаючи слова пісні "Гей там з-за гори, з-за крем'яної" наткнувся на такі рядки:

> Гей там з-за гори, з-за крем'яної
>   **Фана** малинова в'ється.
>   Гей, при долині в чеснім двобою
>   Військо стрілецькеє б'ється.

В СУМі такого слова немає, і в [Словнику діалектних слів](http://proridne.org/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2/) я також нічого не знайшов. Тому взагалі не зрозуміло чи це українське слово.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За 2. описом чудово підходe.

> [ФАНА](https://slovnyk.ua/index.php/index.php?swrd=%D0%A4%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%90), ~и, ж.
>
> 1. За часів Стародавнього Риму — тип провінційного храму, який будувався у лісі, мав квадратну целу і вхід зі східного боку.
> 2. [діал.](http://slovopedia.org.ua/100/53412/1042340.html) Прапор, хоругва

Щодо роду слова:

> [ФА́НА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#13452) — «прапор»
>
> - можливо, через польське посередництво запозичене з німецької мови;
> - нвн. Fáhne (двн. fano) «прапор, знамено» споріднене з дангл., гот. fana «хустка», далі з лат. pannus «тс.», гр. πη̃νάς «тканина»;
> - п. [fana] «прапор»;
>
> Фонетичні та словотвірні варіанти
>
> - фа́нва — «корогва»
> - фа́нойка — «весільний прапорець»

Comment: У моєму селі (Галичина) так називають саме хоругви. Хоча вживається взаємозамінно з хоругвами